# Facing issues while passing form data to a .NET Core API from the Angular side

Tags: angular, api, multipartform-data

We are facing some issues on passing form data to a .NET Core API from Angular.

Also, we have passed headers, but we are still facing the same issues.

Here is an example:

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'});
let options = { headers: headers };
```

How can we fix it?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMkUJ.png]

Comment: Not enough information here. How do you attach the form data to the POST? (hint: you need formData.append)

Comment: this may help https://www.techiediaries.com/angular-formdata/

Answer (score 0):

On the Angular side, create **FormData** using this way:

```
const formData = new FormData;
formData.append('file', file);
formData.append('Id', 323);
```

Add in a Service like this way:

```
 await this.http.post("URL", formData)
```